# US passport card without submitting passport book?

Tags: passports

I have a US passport book. I lost my passport card, and I would like to apply for a new one to make use of the expedited RFID lanes at the Mexican border. I submitted a DS-64 online.

DS-11 only has options under "have you ever had either a passport card/book" for no, lost/stolen, or 'submitted with application'.

I can't submit my passport book, I need it for work. I read somewhere that a birth certificate is also considered 'proof of citizenship'. I can submit that. I also have my old expired passport. Do I absolutely have to send in my current passport book to apply for a card?

Comment: One option may be to call the NPIC (877-487-2778) and set an appointment; you'd need an international ticket within next two weeks. They will check your passport during the appointment and return it to you right away; you can also use this option if your passport is already getting full, as you will get a new passport book (but not card) next day.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if my current passport book was becoming full/close to expiry? I'm ~halfway through my current one.

Comment: I suspect that if you are applying for a passport card alone then they only care about the old card and not the book (they'd also care about the book only if you were applying for both), so just not checking any of those options and not including the book with the application might work. This isn't an answer, though, since I'm not positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question,

Yes I was able to apply without sending in my current passport book. I brought my current passport and ID, and my birth certificate/copy and DS-11 form to an acceptance agent. They had me cross out the `(submitted with application)` next to the "I have a passport book" and initial it, then they filled out the ID check section with both my ID and passport. Then they sent everything in using my birth certificate as proof of citizenship.

Got approved.

Comment: One other option would have been to apply for Global Entry, NEXUS or SENTRI, assuming it's the US RFID lanes you're worried about (I don't think Mexico has RFID lanes).

Comment: Could you please clarify: did they send in your birth certificate or just use it to verify your identity?

Also, would you please be more specific about the ID you used? Was it a DL? Something else?

Comment: They sent in my original birth certificate and a scan of my 2 forms of ID. I brought both my drivers license and passport book as my forms of ID and kept both.