# Applying for a Passport Card while I already have Passport Book

Tags: passports, us-citizens

Hi everyone I was wondering if someone on here could help me with my question. I am looking to apply for a Passport Card. The thing is that I currently own a Passport Book. I don't want to use form DS-82 because I still want my Passport Book to be valid and I don't want to be without it during the processing time. Is it possible for me to use form DS-11 and apply in person and use my birth certificate as Proof of Citizenship. Also if I apply for the Passport Card will my Passport Book definitely still be valid or do I have to tell the State Department specifically to keep it valid and NOT cancel it. I just want to make sure because ultimately I want to have both a valid Passport Book and a valid Passport Card.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: I would like to know if someone has had first had experience with this and if nothing happened to their passport book. Thanks.

Comment: [Here's](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112666/us-passport-card-without-submitting-passport-book) one. The search box at the top of each page is a useful tool.